# Is there a machine learning tool that works directly on databases?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, databases

Is there a database that can work with machine learning directly?

I do not want to use Python or R to build my machine learning pipelines.

Is there a database that does this natively?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "work with ML directly". Do you mean a database with an available ML extension (e.g. like [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) for PostGreSQL but providing ML functions rather than GIS functions)?

Comment: @Galen Yes, is there anything like that?

Comment: Querying subsets of data is often feasible. What motivated this question?

Answer (score 2):

There are many options. One is Amazon Redshift which supports machine learning in SQL. Another option is Google Cloud’s BigQuery ML.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, depending on the DB that you're using there are different options.
e.g. Machine Learning Services for SQL Servers is executing everything in-database level.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/sql-server-machine-learning-services?view=sql-server-ver16